# Nautilus hard-sorts by modification-date, driving me insane

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I have found that when I cleaned out my system and installed Ubuntu 16.04.1, Nautilus sorting order messed up.

Instead of sorting by name in ascending order, it sorts by name in descending order by default and then sorts by modification date as files and folders change. But it still puts folders before files as it should. I have tried changing preferences and the `Arrange Items` menu does not work. I have also tried `dconf-editor`(doesn't work). My work PC with 16.04 LTS works fine. Should I back up my files and downgrade to 16.04? I have also found that Chrome randomly freezes after the reinstall, but that's a separate issue.

P.S. I really wish someone would tag this 16.04.1 instead of 16.04, as this issue is just not there in 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Nautilus and hover your mouse over the top-left screen line and this Menu line appears:

`File Edit View Go Bookmarks Help`

Click on `View`. A drop down menu appears and you need to uncheck `Reversed Order` option.

Comment: Thanks a million! Unchecking `Reversed Order` and setting `By Name` in `View` solved the problem. I wonder why it was set like that by default, and why there is a duplicate setting in `Edit > Preferences > Arrange Items`.

Comment: You're most welcome. I don't know know why they split stuff over two areas. But "it is what it is" as they used to say 5 or 6 years ago.